# What do we call unary operators of differing directions of operation?

Tags: convention

Suppose you have two unary operators $!$ being the factorial and $\partial_1$ being the partial derivative of a function w.r.t. its first parameter.

$$ n!m $$
$$ f \partial_1 g $$

The $!$ operator operates on an argument on its left side ($n$), whereas $\partial_1$ operates on its right side ($g$).
Associativity comes to mind but it doesn't quite capture the property. What do we call the differing properties of both operators?

Comment: We call them left and right operators. I can never remember which one is which though. (Is $!$ a right operator because it stands to the right of $n$, or is it a left operator because it affects whatever is on the left of it? I can never keep that straight.)

Comment: @Arthur: I've never heard of "left and right operators". "Prefix" and "postfix" is the standard terminology.

Comment: @RobArthan I'm an algebraist, we talk about left right multiplication all the time, and we often think about the application of a unary operator as multiplication (at least if it's nice enough). Granted, I have never heard about the factorial referred to as such, but the differential operators are certainly common enough.

Comment: @Arthur: sure, but when you are talking about a group or a ring acting on the left or the right of a set or a module, you don't talk about "left operators" or "right operators" but rather "left action" or "right action" or "left multiplication" or "right multiplication".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $n!$, $!$ is called a *postfix* operator. $\partial_1$ in $\partial_1 g$ is called a *prefix* operator.